# How to make the round shaped corner wpf form

Tags: wpf, xaml

hi want to use the corner radius in the mainwindows of WPF. but when i use border control to do this it not work.

my question is that i want my application with round shaped corner. i did this with usercontrol but unable to do this with main form in WPF.

so please tell me how i do this.

here is my xaml code.

```
<window....>
 <Grid>
     <Border CornerRadius="10">
       <Grid>
          -------------
       </Grid>
     </Border>
 </Grid>
</window>
```

Comment: There are no forms in WPF; call them Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can add to the Border:
    **BorderBrush="Red"** and
    **BorderThickness="1"**

The border with round corners will show up.

```
<Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
    ...your code
</Border>
```

Comment: i also did this but no effect in main form. still rectangular shap.

Comment: What do you mean "main form"? The Windows frame that your screen is placed on?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
<Window ...
        WindowStyle="None"
        Background="Transparent">
<Border CornerRadius="10"
        Background="White">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: i got it. just use following.

<Window AllowsTransparency="True"  WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent">
 <Grid>
     <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Background="White">
       <Grid>
          -------------
       </Grid>
     </Border>
 </Grid>
</Window>

Answer (score 0):

Go to App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="RoundedButtons">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Margin="5" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#d9d9d9" Background="#595959" CornerRadius="10">
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

And then, when you want to apply this style to your button

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource RoundedButtons}"/>
```

Comment: For "Window", the content presenter should be "Stretch" and not "Center" for a window.